# DIV left/right onclick

Tags: jquery, html, slide

I wanted to slide a DIV to left or right on click. but it seems i dont get it to work.

Here is the **code**:

```
  $(".left").click(function(){
     $("#box").hide( "slide", 
                 { direction: "left"  }, 2000 );
  });

  $(".right").click(function(){
     $("#box").show( "slide", 
                  {direction: "right" }, 2000 );
  });
```

Can anybody help me on this one? Would be great!

**UPDATE**

```
$(".left").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({marginLeft:'-500px'},'slow');                   
});
```

i tried this code and it works it moves to the left but when it slide to left it must disapear in the DIV

Answer (score 0):

make one div named 'box' and make two buttons after it give them a touch and you will get your div moving correctly .. if you want to make your div hidden , see the code given above
else make a toggle function of slide using one button .

i hope my answer is helpfull